# SQL não realiza o calculo com valores NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Tenho uma consulta onde tenho 3 colunas agrupadas e ultima totalizando as 3, o problema é para o Edson  a consulta não está TOTALIZANDO.

TOTAL = CREDITO - (DESCONTO + BONIFICACOES)

O total do Edson tem que dar 266,49 mas meu código não calcula, devido o "desconto" ainda estar NULL.

[image: fotobd]

```sql
SELECT
  U.NOME,
  CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC1) as NUMERIC (15,2)) AS CREDITO_FLEX,
  CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC2) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) AS DESCONTO_PRODUTOS_FLEX,
  CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC3) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) AS BONIFICACOES,
  CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC1) as NUMERIC (15,2)) - CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC3) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) - CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC2) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) AS TOTAL_FLEX_VENDEDOR
FROM
  COTACAOI R
  LEFT JOIN COTACAO C ON R.ID_COTACAO = C.ID
  LEFT JOIN CADUSUARIO U ON C.ID_VENDEDOR = U.ID
WHERE
  R.ID_PEDIDO IS NOT NULL AND
  R.CAMPOADICIONAL1 = 'SIM'
GROUP BY
  U.NOME
```

Comment: *"O total do Edson tem que dar 266,49 mas meu código não calcula"* pode colocar um exemplo com os dados da tabela que tem de dar esse resultado? Pq faz o cast, qual é o tipo de dados das colunas CAMPOCALC1, CAMPOCALC2 e CAMPOCALC3?

Comment: Você tem que entender o significado de `NULL`. NULL significa que o valor daquele atributo é desconhecido, é uma ausência de valor, assim qualquer operação que envolva NULL dará como resultado NULL. Até uma comparação, utilizando algum dos operadores de comparação (`>`, `<`. `=`, `!=`, `>=` ou `<=`) envolvendo um NULL dará como resultado NULL. O SQL prevê um operador especial para você verificar se um campo é ou não NULL, o `IS NULL` e `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Caso, por razões especiais de sua aplicação, você queira considerar como zero um campo que contenha NULL utilize a função COALESCE: `COALESCE(campo, 0)`. Esta função pode ter uma lista de campos como parâmetros e irá retornar o primeiro campo não NULL. Para o seu caso `SUM(COALESCE(R.CAMPOCALC1,0))` e a mesma coisa nas demais acumulações.

Comment: @RicardoPontual o exemplo estava acima, total = credito - (desconto + bonificacoes) sobre o cast é alterar o numero de dígitos após a virgula... todos os dados são numericos.

Comment: Por isso que é importante definir um valor default para colunas que armazenam valores, com 0. Sempre. E restringir a possibilidade de gravar null. NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar a função ISNULL para ver se resolve conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT
  U.NOME,
  CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC1) as NUMERIC (15,2)) AS CREDITO_FLEX,
  CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(R.CAMPOCALC2) THEN 0 ELSE R.CAMPOCALC2 END) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) AS DESCONTO_PRODUTOS_FLEX,
  CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC3) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) AS BONIFICACOES,
  CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC1) as NUMERIC (15,2)) - CAST(SUM(R.CAMPOCALC3) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) - CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(R.CAMPOCALC2) THEN 0 ELSE R.CAMPOCALC2 END ) AS NUMERIC(15,2)) AS TOTAL_FLEX_VENDEDOR
```

Comment: é possível também realizar o mesmo feito com coalesce, fica menos complexo também

Comment: Então @gabriel agradeço o retorno, consegui com o case mas pensei que o problema estava na coluna "DESCONTO" mas o problema estava no "TOTAL" alterei e agora deu certo.